# How to get property type for array class inner properties

Tags: c#, propertyinfo

I have tried to get a property type for array properties

```
[Serializable]
public class Orders
{
    public long OrderID { get; set; }
    public string CustomerID { get; set; }
    public int EmployeeID { get; set; }
    public double Freight { get; set; }
    public string ShipCountry { get; set; }
    public string ShipCity { get; set; }
    public Customer[] customer {get; set;}
}

public class Customer
{
    public string OtherAddress { get; set; }
    public int CustNum { get; set; }

}
```

I need to get type of **Orders.Customer.OtherAddress** or **Orders.Customer.0.OtherAddress** index based. **dataSource** is the list of Orders.

```
Type type = dataSource.GetElementType();

PropertyInfo propInfo = type.GetProperty("Customer");

DefaultMemberAttribute defaultMember = 
(DefaultMemberAttribute)Attribute.GetCustomAttribute(propInfo.PropertyType, 
typeof(DefaultMemberAttribute));
                    propInfo = 
propInfo.PropertyType.GetProperty("CustNum" , new Type[] { 
typeof(int) });
```

How can i proceed ?

Comment: Some reason you can't use `var a = dataSource[0].customer[0].OtherAddress;`?

Comment: Hi @JohnWu i am using dynamic dataSource. so i need unique solution.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Recursive routine to obtain PropertyInfo](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8095180/recursive-routine-to-obtain-propertyinfo)

Comment: I don't know what you mean. Are you saying `dataSource` is typed as a `dynamic` ?

Comment: Hi @JohnWu dataSource is not a dynamic type. The data will be assigned dynamically

Comment: Then what type is it? `DbSet<T>`? Anonymous? There is no commonly understood meaning of "data will be assigned dynamically" so you will have to explain that, or provide code and show us.

Answer (score 0):

OP, your question isn't very clear.... "using dynamic datasource" could mean a lot of different things.  However, whether the reference to your data source is a strongly typed object, a dynamic, or just an object, the object being referenced is still a strongly-typed class of some kind. Unless for some reason you can't set a reference to its type library, you should not need to use any reflection. At most a simple cast will do it. With a dynamic, that isn't even necessary.

For example, if you have this interface:

```
public interface IRepository
{
    dynamic GetListAsDynamic();
    object  GetListAsObject();
}
```

...and a class that implements it....

```
public class OrderRepository : IRepository
{
    public dynamic GetListAsDynamic()
    {
        return new List<Order>
        {
            new Order
            {
                customer = new [] {new Customer { OtherAddress = "1234 Foo St" } }
            }
        };
    }
    public object GetListAsObject()
    {
        return new List<Order>
        {
            new Order
            {
                customer = new [] {new Customer { OtherAddress = "1234 Bar St" } }
            }
        };
    }
}
```

You can still access the other address without any reflection:

```
public class Program
{
    public static void TestDynamic()
    {
        var repo = new OrderRepository();
        var orders = repo.GetListAsDynamic();
        var order = orders[0];
        var customers = order.customer;
        var customer = customers[0];

        Console.WriteLine("And the customer dynamic's other address is.... '{0}'", customer.OtherAddress);
    }

    public static void TestObject()
    {
        var repo = new OrderRepository();
        var orders = repo.GetListAsObject() as List<Order>;
        var order = orders[0];
        var customers = order.customer;
        var customer = customers[0];

        Console.WriteLine("And the customer object's other address is.... '{0}'", customer.OtherAddress);
    }

    public static void Main()
    {
        TestDynamic();
        TestObject();
    }
}
```

Output:

```
And the customer dynamic's other address is.... '1234 Foo St'
And the customer object's other address is.... '1234 Bar St'
```

[Working code on DotNetFiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/8B17Fc)

Comment: Hi John, I want to use this structure to some other class definition. So, I trying unique solution.

Answer (score 0):

I assume that you are looking for a "generic" answer that could be applied to other, unknown, situations.  However, I am not sure how generic / unknown your situation will be.  I came up with this which gets the the type of "OtherAddress" but you will still need to know some of the field names.  If you want a totally generic approach, you will need a more extensive extraction of the various properties.  The type listed in the debug window is string.

```
public void GetTypeInfo()
{
    Orders o = new Orders {customer = new Customer[] {new Customer()}};

    dataSource.Add(o);

    PropertyInfo info1 = dataSource[0].GetType().GetProperty("customer");

    Array c = (Array) info1.GetValue(dataSource[0], null);

    Type info2 = c.GetValue(0).GetType();

    PropertyInfo info3 = info2.GetProperty("OtherAddress");

    Debug.WriteLine("type| " + info3.PropertyType.Name);
}
```